# Ubuntu 12.04 kernel 3.8 Wireless not working (BCM43142 chipset)

Tags: 12.04, wireless, drivers, bluetooth

I have a Dell Laptop with a BCM43142 chip on the wireless card. If I'll stay on 3.5 kernel it works with wl driver, but the Bluetooth is not finding any device (like it is off).
I tried to upgrade the kernel to 3.8 or 3.13 but there I don't have the wl driver anymore. Searching the net I've found out this:
http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#Known_PCI_devices
that states: BCM43142 driver is not supported.

The question:
1. How can I have my Wireless work with higher version kernels.
2. When BCM43142 will be supported?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using the 3.13 kernel you will likely have to download from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+package/bcmwl-kernel-source
Download the 32 or 64 bit depending on your install

Comment: Please read my answer to this thread. I already have installed the bcmwl-kernel-source (although not on the latest version. But it seems that fixing the Bluetooth for this specific chip also fixed the wireless.

Answer (score 0):

I finally have my Dell (with wireless+bluetooth BCM43142) working on wireless & Bluetooth with kernels >= 3.13.
I did somehow by chance, but it is working now.

Yesterday I fixed my Bluetooth as here (read all answers before start):
[How to setup the BCM43142 Bluetooth](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533043/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-dell-inspiron-15-3521)

Today I want to verify user300665's suggestion in his answer here. I found out that I already have bcmwl-kernel-source installed in the system, although not on the latest version. I installed kernel 3.13-37 and I was hit by the fact that my wireless is working fine now, this way. So I did all the upgrades to maximum for 12.04.

My guess is that fixing the Bluetooth by providing/loading the right firmware for this RAM chip, I somehow fixed the wireless too. The working driver is wl, loaded automatic by the kernel.

I think this thread is now SOLVED.