# Bluetooth not working on BCM43142 on 14.10

Tags: drivers, dell, bluetooth, 14.10

I have an issue on a Dell Vostro 3560 with a BCM43142 where the Bluetooth doesn't work even with the proprietary drivers installed. The WiFi works just fine. I'm running a fresh installation of Ubuntu 14.10. The only time it worked was when I had Dell preinstalled Ubuntu 12.04.

dmesg | grep Bluetooth gives
[ 4967.683179] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found

I don't have a Windows installation I can get files from

From lsusb
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0

apt-get shows
bcmwl-kernel-source is already the newest version.

This should have fixed my problem but it did not
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1065400
Why?

Any solution?

Comment: Appears to be a related question http://askubuntu.com/questions/459654/drivers-for-broadcom-bcm43142-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bluetooth not working on ubuntu 14.04 with dell inspiron 15-3521](http://askubuntu.com/questions/533043/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-dell-inspiron-15-3521)

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue. I read some answers and this is the gist of it:

1. Find ID of your device:

> $ lsusb | grep Bluetooth

My output for example:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
```

from which **0a5c:21d7** should be remembered.

2. Get a hex file for your device:
   After searching for bluetooth drivers in Google I have chosen this download: 
   http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/BLUETOOTH/Broadcom/Broadcom-43142-Bluetooth-40-Adapter-Driver-12007030-for-Windows-8.shtml#download
3. **How to get the right hex file.**

So I have the id of the chip: 0a5c:21d7 and a bunch of the hex files from the downloaded archive. How can I get the right one for me? The trick is to investigate the .inf file that instructs windows what to install. Searching for 21D7 (note the capital D instead of 'd') I get this:

%Dell1704.DeviceDesc%=RAMUSB21D7, USB\VID_0A5C&PID_21D7 ; BRCM Generic 43142A0 RAMUSB

The USB/VID&PID is what I get on lsusb: capital(0a5c:21d7). The RAMUSB21D7 is what I need to search next in the inf file (it is the device's description).

And this is my result:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;RAMUSB21D7;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

[RAMUSB21D7.CopyList]
bcbtums.sys
btwampfl.sys
BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0122.0126.hex
```

And the hex file I shall use is **BCM43142A0_001.001.011.0122.0126.hex** Extract this into **home directory**.

4. Type this:

> dmesg | grep Bluetooth

Result according to your issue is:

> [ 4967.683179] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: patch
>   brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd not found

It will tell the name and file its looking for. I your case it is:**brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd**

5. Convert the correct hex to hcd file.
   Open terminal and type these commands:

> sudo apt-get install git
>
> git clone git://github.com/jessesung/hex2hcd.git
>
> cd hex2hcd
>
> make
>
> ./hex2hcd ../BCMxxxx.xxx.xxx.xx.hex BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd (Correct
>        hex file and required hcd name here)
>
> sudo cp BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm