# bluetooth not detecting devices (firmware error

Tags: bluetooth, firmware

my bluetooth is not able to detect any of the other bluetooth devices ... i was using windows before and the bluetooth was working fine ...

> `dmesg | grep firmware`

results in "[   15.275727] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load failed with error -2
"

```
lsusb | grep Bluetooth
```

results in "Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0"

which clearly states that there is bluetooth adapter but i am having firmware issues.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bluetooth Broadcom 43142 isn't working on ubuntu 15.04](http://askubuntu.com/questions/632336/bluetooth-broadcom-43142-isnt-working-on-ubuntu-15-04)

Answer (score 0):

The broadcom BCM43142 Bluetooth adapter needs an **additional** (updated) **firmware** to function *correctly*.

Look at [Bluetooth not working on ubuntu 14.04 with dell inspiron 15-3521](https://askubuntu.com/questions/533043/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-dell-inspiron-15-3521) for instruction on how to do that.

In short, you need to extract the firmware from the *Windows* driver and copy the resulting .hcd file into /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd

Answer (score 0):

```
wget https://www.dropbox.com/s/9ryy3ir1tby6wrf/fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd
sudo cp fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

And it should work with the latest 3.13 kernel from Ubuntu

If you happen to have the 3.16 or newer kernel, check `uname -a` then

```
sudo cp fw-0a5c_21d7 /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd
sudo modprobe -r btusb
sudo modprobe btusb
```

Comment: when i type  "sudo cp fw-0a5c_21d7 /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd" .. it says cp: cannot stat ‘fw-0a5c_21d7’: No such file or directory .... sry i am a new user ... i might be sounding stupid here..

Comment: Should have been `sudo cp fw-0a5c_21d7.hcd /lib/firmware/brcm/BCM43142A0-0a5c-21d7.hcd`

Comment: it shows connected but  i am not able to send files ...it doesnt show any option to send... although it connects my music library of my phonw .... when i type dmesg | grep firmware
 now it shows  [   15.832056] Bluetooth: hci0: BCM: firmware hci_ver=06 hci_rev=00e5 lmp_ver=06 lmp_subver=210b

Comment: You may need to `sudo apt-get install obexftp` to share files

Comment: now there is no bluetooth option in the notification bar ,... if i go to the settings i can only turn it on but can't turn on the visibility

Comment: You may need to `sudo modprobe -r btusb` and then `sudo modprobe btusb`