# Can't enable Bluetooth. `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` does not help

Tags: bluetooth, broadcom

I attempted all the solutions posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/474839/bluetooth-is-disable-on-ubuntu-14-04).

The command `sudo rfkill unblock bluetooth` is not working.

I can move the switch to "on" but it still says "Bluetooth is disabled" in the menu on the left.  Exiting the settings menu and coming back moves the switch back to "off".  My system is a dual boot with Windows 10.

Any ideas?

```
$ lsusb
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0a5c:21e8 Broadcom Corp. BCM20702A0 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 1532:0037 Razer USA, Ltd 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 1b1c:1b13 Corsair 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 002: ID 054c:05c4 Sony Corp. DualShock 4
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub


$ lspci -nn

00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 Host Bridge [1022:9600]
00:02.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780 PCI to PCI bridge (ext gfx port 0) [1022:9603]
00:07.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 3) [1022:9607]
00:0a.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] RS780/RS880 PCI to PCI bridge (PCIE port 5) [1022:9609]
00:11.0 SATA controller [0106]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 SATA Controller [IDE mode] [1002:4390]
00:12.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:12.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:12.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]    
00:13.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI0 Controller [1002:4397]
00:13.1 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0 USB OHCI1 Controller [1002:4398]
00:13.2 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB EHCI Controller [1002:4396]
00:14.0 SMBus [0c05]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 SMBus Controller [1002:4385] (rev 3c)
00:14.1 IDE interface [0101]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 IDE Controller [1002:439c]
00:14.2 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) [1002:4383]
00:14.3 ISA bridge [0601]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 LPC host controller [1002:439d]
00:14.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 PCI to PCI Bridge [1002:4384]
00:14.5 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SB7x0/SB8x0/SB9x0 USB OHCI2 Controller [1002:4399]
00:18.0 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 0 [1022:1600]
00:18.1 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 1 [1022:1601]
00:18.2 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 2 [1022:1602]
00:18.3 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 3 [1022:1603]
00:18.4 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 4 [1022:1604]
00:18.5 Host bridge [0600]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 15h Processor Function 5 [1022:1605]
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Fiji [Radeon R9 FURY / NANO Series] [1002:7300] (rev c8)
01:00.1 Audio device [0403]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device [1002:aae8]
02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1042 SuperSpeed USB Host Controller [1b21:1042]
03:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 09)
```

Comment: Can you paste the output of `lsusb` and `lspci -nn` command output [back in to your question](http://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/668229)?

Comment: @P.-H.Lin I posted the output.

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2231813

Comment: Related:http://askubuntu.com/questions/818956/bluetooth-is-not-working-ubuntu-gnome-16-04

Comment: Related:http://askubuntu.com/questions/533043/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-14-04-with-dell-inspiron-15-3521?rq=1

Comment: You could give us a few more details about your question? Version that you use of Ubuntu, environment, etc.

Comment: @Alberto I'm using 16.04. Don't know what you mean by environment.

Answer (score 0):

Before doing anything else take a look at this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/787023/bluetooth-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04-lts)

Other things you can do.

To install bluetooth on Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial Xerus) run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bluetooth
```

Another similar question that can serve you :[Connect to bluetooth device from command line](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48001/connect-to-bluetooth-device-from-command-line?rq=1)